# Unable to create session in Quickblox in node.js

Tags: node.js, quickblox

Getting Error 401 Unauthorized while creating session in Quickblox here is code i am using to create session in quickblox

```
var QBUser = {email: "user@user.com",password: "password123"}

QB.createSession(QBUser, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('QB >>> Something went wrong: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    } else {
        console.log('QB at create session >>> result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

let me know why i am getting 401 error and how to resolve this bug?

Comment: As per docs you need to use QB.login prior to QB.createSession did you do that?

Comment: while cram i using QB.login using bellow method getting error ""Token is require     QB.login(QBUser, function(err, user){
  if (user) {
    console.log('QB >>> user: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
  } else  {
    console.log('QB at login user >>> Something went wrong: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
  }
});d"  I am using bellow method to login user

Comment: Did you call QB.init before this?

Comment: yes I called  QB.init before  this

Comment: 401 Unauthorized means that your auth data is wrong (email or password are incorrect), so please check it first

Comment: I am signup with Google, I  am able to login same username and password to admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it's work for me.

```js
QB.createSession(function(err, result) {
  // callback function
  QB.users.create(params, function(err, user){
  if (user) {
    // success
    console.log(user);
  } else  {
    // error
     console.log(err);
  }
});
});
```